# Simple Excel Macro does not work when called from AppleScript

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

The following macro copies column C (from 3 worksheets) and inserts it in the same position. It works perfectly when I run from Excel.

```
Public Sub CreateNewMonth()
' CreateNewMonth Macro
' Create New Month in all Tabs

Dim lastDate As Date
Dim newDate As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetName As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Item(1)

' Get the last date from the "TOTAL" sheet
lastDate = wb.Sheets("TOTAL").Range("C1").Value
' Calculate the new date by adding one month
newDate = DateAdd("m", 1, lastDate)

Dim sheetsToChange As Variant
sheetsToChange = Array("A", "B", "TOTAL")

' Loop through each sheet in the list
For Each sheetName In sheetsToChange
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    
    'Application.CutCopyMode = True
    ws.Columns("C:C").Copy 'Not working when called from AppleScript
    ws.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'Not working when called from AppleScript
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Set the new date in new cell C1
    ws.Range("C1").Value = newDate 'Working when called from AppleScript
Next sheetName


End Sub
```

This workbook keeps the costs and benefits per month in different centre costs (Sheet A and Sheet B) and sums it up in Sheet TOTAL. In every sheet there are formula cells, that I'm able to maintain correctly with this operation. However, when I call this macro from AppleScript (I have this apple script in `Library/Application Scripts/com-microsoft.Excel/` and I have authorized Macros to run by default), it does not create a new column (by copying and inserting) and only updates the date with `ws.Range("C1").Value = newDate`.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open "Macintosh HD:Users:myuser:Test.xlsm"
    delay 2 -- Delay for 2 seconds to ensure Excel is ready
    run VB macro ("CreateNewMonth" & "()")
end tell
```

I already tried different combinations of `Application.CutCopyMode`, but couldn't make this work. Any idea on how may I solve this?

Comment: FWIW, which may be nothing, I couldn't get your VBA script to work directly. It choked on the `.Copy`. I'm using an old version of excel (2011) but I think that all of the commands in your script are supported. Dunno if it would be of value to you but it would be possible to use applescript to perform all of the tasks in the vba script.

Comment: I’m using current office version, and this works when invoked from excel. Although I’d prefer to use a macro, could you point me to a applescript-based solution?

Comment: FYI, *CutCopyMode* is when you see the marching ants around the selection after using `cut` or `copy`. When you set to either false or true, you turn off the marching ants and the latter puts the contents of the selection onto the clipboard. I don't think it has any useful relevance to your objective. Your script doesn't rely on the selection/clipboard but if it did, then presumably it would be in *copy mode* upon copying the column.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand what you're trying to do, this should work. However, dates are always a concern because of different formats. I use a `yyyymmdd` format so you might have to tweak it to get it to align with your locale and settings.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set wb to workbook 1
    tell wb
        
        set lastDate to value of range "C1" of sheet "TOTAL"
        set {y, m, d} to {year, month, day} of lastDate
        set m to m + 1
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
        set newDate to {m, d, y} as text
        tell me to set newDate to date string of date newDate
        
        set sheetstoChange to {"asof06-sched.csv", "B", "TOTAL"}
        repeat with sheetName in sheetstoChange
            set ws to sheet sheetName
            set dateCell to cell "C1" of ws
            
            set cCol to intersect range1 used range of ws range2 range "C:C" of ws
            copy range cCol
            insert into range cCol shift shift to right
            
            set value of dateCell to newDate
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

I use `intersect` to limit the number of rows being processed but it's optional.

Comment: yes this solves the issue but I need a macro that I can run manually (from Excel) and was trying to figure out why this working macro can't be called from Applescript. Do you have any idea why this happens? (also, I'm calling this from python code, so maybe I could implement the same logic directly in python. However, the ideal would be to call an existing macro, and for that I'm calling Applescript from within python).

Comment: Earlier you mentioned that the macro did activate and run but just didn't complete all of its tasks. So perhaps the problem isn't that the macro isn't being called but rather in its implementation. Something to try… given that the macro did function when affecting a range object but failed when attempting to affect a column object, what happens when you attempt the `copy/insert into` using a range, eg use something like `intersect` to make the column into a range first? Also, in addition to range.copy, use range.insert rather than range.insert shift.

Comment: I should note that I have nothing to add regarding integrating python into the affair.